# RStudio spontaneously self-updates to a higher version

Tags: r, rstudio

I wonder if somebody could advise on how I can stop my computer from spontaneously changing the RStudio version from RStudio-1.3.1093 to Version 1.4.1106 (which makes some of my scripts to crash).

I do this. Uninstall RStudio (Version 1.4.1106). Delete everything RStudio related from %localappdata%\RStudio. Install RStudio-1.3.1093. But then a few days later I load RStudio and the version is again 1.4.1106 (and my scripts begin to crash).

Comment: Try with the latest version, v1.4.1717, as there was an issue with 1106 for Apple M1 users, which I assume is your issue. If it isn't, then you would need to provide more detail as to your issue.

Comment: Thank you Phil. I am not using a MAC. It is a Microsoft laptop with Windows 10 OS. What other details would be needed?

Comment: Contact RStudio if the issue still occurs with the latest version v1.4.1717.